# Getting Bluetooth on Windows 10 Virtual Machine (Guest) - VirtualBox / Disabling Bluetooth Daemon

Tags: bluetooth, virtualbox

How can I use bluetooth on my Windows 10 guest machine using my built-in macOS Bluetooth chip.

When I try adding it as a USB device it come up with

`Failed to attach USB device Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller [0150] to the Virtual Machine Windows VM`

**Details**

`Could not find USB Device with uuid {164bc863-a9e1-4f47-b389-36afadb8c6d5}`

**Edit 1:**

Aftersome futher reasearch I found out that it will work if I am able to the the Bluetooth host service/daemom. How can I do this?

**Edit 2:**
Also found that Parrallels desktop is able to use built in bluetooth without you needing to do anything. This proves it *is* possible to use Built in Bluetooth on a VM. How can you achieve this in VirtualBox?

**General Machine Info**

**OS**:`macOS Catalina (10.15.3)`

**Computer** `2015 Macbook Air`

Any solution to try and fix this would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying to get this to work for a few hours

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this, is that the *host* (your Mac) needs to completely release the Bluetooth adapter so that VBox can take “ownership” of it.

To see what’s loaded issue the command.

```
kextstatus | grep -i bluet
```

All of those kexts need to be unloaded.  The problem is, macOS will respawn the processes automatically.

There’s a couple options you can try:

- use a seperate USB Bluetooth adapter
- Use a different host OS (FreeBSD can do this) that will allow you to manually load/unload support dor different divices.

macOS, especially with all of the new protections implemented in Catalina won’t allow you to do this.

Comment: Is there anyway to unload this kexts permenantly (eg. moving their plists to a different location and restarting?)

Comment: Not that I know of.  Even if you do remove it by disabling SIP, the very next update reinstalls and reactivates it.  What is your specific use case?  Maybe we can find an alternate solution.

Comment: Parallels desktop is able to use built-in bluetooth on a Windows VM. I just want want to be able to connect & use Bluetooth from a VM. Is there anyway to achieve this functionality on VirtualBox